# Creating Word Doc from Excel VBA, insert TOC on 3rd or 4th page (section 2)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am creating a word document from Excel using VBA and want to insert a Table of Contents at the start of section 2 or on what will be either the 3rd or 4th page depending on what is on the first few pages.  The document changes based on many variables.
I thought that surely this has been asked and answered many times over but I can't find much and nothing that I can make work.

I used this from another SO post but it only moves to the second page.

```
wdApp.ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
  wdApp.ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents.Add Range:=wdApp.ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0), RightAlignPageNumbers:=True, _
     UseHeadingStyles:=True, IncludePageNumbers:=True, UseHyperlinks:=True, _
     HidePageNumbersInWeb:=True, UseOutlineLevels:=False
  'Insert a page break before existing content
  wdApp.ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
```

I have a cover page then two/three pages of tables and text then the TOC and then and INTRODUCTION Page.  Currently I have a section break before the Intro page thinking I could just set the TOC to go there but all the iterations have put the TOC on page 1 or this one which has put it on page 2.
I tried this which initially put it in the right place at the time but as the rest of the script ran through the TOC slid down the document until it stopped at the end and it ruined all of my formatting.

```
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
  With ActiveDocument
    .TablesOfContents.Add Range:=Selection.Range, RightAlignPageNumbers:= _
      True, UseHeadingStyles:=True, UpperHeadingLevel:=1, _
      LowerHeadingLevel:=9, IncludePageNumbers:=True, AddedStyles:="", _
      UseHyperlinks:=True, HidePageNumbersInWeb:=True, UseOutlineLevels:= _True
    .TablesOfContents(1).TabLeader = wdTabLeaderDots
    .TablesOfContents.Format = wdIndexIndent
```

My script is quite long so I have only included the word snippet below but happy to provide more detail if needed.  Does anyone know how I can get the table of contents to go exactly where I want it?

```
With wdApp
.Visible = True
.Activate
.Documents.Open ("C:\Users\v1.dotm")
    With .Selection
'Headers
    .Sections.First.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
 'Cover Page
      
   .InsertBreak Type:=7
'Page 2
   
    .BoldRun 'Switch bold on
        .TypeText ClientHeading
        .BoldRun 'Switch bold off
            ' Revision Table
            RevTable.Copy 'DoEvents
            .Range.PasteExcelTable _
            LinkedToExcel:=False, _
            WordFormatting:=False, _
            RTF:=False
   .InsertBreak Type:=7
 'Page 3 and/or 4

    .InsertBreak Type:=7
   
wdApp.ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
  wdApp.ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents.Add Range:=wdApp.ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0), RightAlignPageNumbers:=True, _
     UseHeadingStyles:=True, IncludePageNumbers:=True, UseHyperlinks:=True, _
     HidePageNumbersInWeb:=True, UseOutlineLevels:=False
  'Insert a page break before existing content
  wdApp.ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak


'Introduction Page
    .InsertBreak Type:=7
    .Style = wdApp.ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
    .TypeText Text:="INTRODUCTION"
    .TypeParagraph
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCentre
            .Style = wdApp.ActiveDocument.Styles("Body Text")
        .TypeText TextToInsert
```

Comment: If you used a proper Word template with all the boilerplate content in-situ, you wouldn't need to create the TOC in code - all you'd need to do once you've inserted the variable content is update all fields in the document. Indeed, if your workbook has a suitable layout, you could even automate a mailmerge, thus eliminating almost all your VBA code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Note:*** Below is Word VBA code. Please qualify the object with `wdApp` (eg. wdApp.ActiveDocument) if you run it with Excel VBA.

```vb
Sub InsertTOC()
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim rng As Range
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    ' Check if the document contains at least two sections
    If doc.Sections.Count < 2 Then
        MsgBox "The document must have at least two sections."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Insert a paragraph at the beginning of the section
    Set rng = doc.Sections(2).Range
    rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
    rng.InsertParagraphAfter
    rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    ' Insert the table of contents ** code from OP
    doc.TablesOfContents.Add Range:=rng, RightAlignPageNumbers:= _
      True, UseHeadingStyles:=True, UpperHeadingLevel:=1, _
      LowerHeadingLevel:=9, IncludePageNumbers:=True, AddedStyles:="", _
      UseHyperlinks:=True, HidePageNumbersInWeb:=True, UseOutlineLevels:=True
    doc.TablesOfContents(1).TabLeader = wdTabLeaderDots
    doc.TablesOfContents.Format = wdIndexIndent
    ' Update the table of contents
    doc.TablesOfContents(1).Update
    Set doc = Nothing
    Set sec = Nothing
    Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [TablesOfContents.Add method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.tablesofcontents.add?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Range.InsertParagraphAfter method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.insertparagraphafter?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: For some reason I keep getting stuck when trying to reference Section 2.  I get a type mismatch error at 
   `Set rng = doc.Sections(2).Range`
When I click on the header on that page it says First Page Header -Section 2-
But no matter the what I put in my script it doesn't seem to recognise Sections(2).  I had the same issue when trying to do different headers and footers.

Comment: I recommend creating a new Word document with a minimum of two sections to initially test the code.

Comment: I added another section break after the first page and removed the `rng.InsertParagraphAfter` line and set the Sections to `Sections(3)` and that has put the TOC exactly where I needed it to.  Thanks for the help, clarification, and direction @taller